# Connect-ExchangeOnline with credentials - no browser

Tags: powershell, exchange

I need to `Connect-ExchangeOnline` without a browser. I would use the `-Credential` parameter, but the help says:

```
Don't use this parameter for accounts that use multi-factor authentication (MFA).
```

I can do the following, but it still requires interactive use to enter the password.

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline -InlineCredential -UserPrincipalName jdoe@myco.com
```

How can I automate getting connected without user interaction?

Comment: Why do you need to do that? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/connect-exchangeonline?view=exchange-ps Several unattended examples here

Comment: does the target require MFA? because if it does, you will not be able to connect without user intervention.

Comment: I used `-Credential` and it appears to have worked. That seems to suggest that an MFA requirement is the client application's choice and not a server/organizational configuration.

Comment: @lit Exchange Online uses the Entra organization/tenant's conditional access policies to determine when/how a user needs to provide MFA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `-InlineCredential` works at all, then `-Credential` will work too.

If the account uses 2FA, you will get an error for either method:

```
AADSTS50158: External security challenge not satisfied. User will be redirected to another 
page or authentication provider to satisfy additional authentication challenges. 
Trace ID: XXX Correlation ID: YYY Timestamp: ZZZ
```

---

A 2FA sign in **always** requires user interaction. To use exchange online commands without interaction, you need a separate user account with 2FA not required.